# Syntax error in select case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, case, for-xml-path

I started learning SQL few days ago and I've the following query which gives me an error near "case" and I can't seem to figure it out:

```
SELECT * , Stuff((SELECT ', ' +  CAST( orderid as varchar(10))
      FROM( oitems t2 
 case when (ocardtype in ('PayPal','Sofort') OR
        ocardtype in ('mastercard','visa') and
        odate is not null) then 
              FOR XML PATH(''), 1, 2, '') [Proccessed] else  FOR XML PATH(''), 1, 2, '') [NotProccessed] end)
                      FROM orders t1
    Group by orderid,t1.odate, t1.ocardtype
```

I guess you get what the this code is supposed to do, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to use `select case`.

```
oitems table

+---------+-----------+----------+
| orderid | catalogid | numitems |
+---------+-----------+----------+
| o737    |       353 |        1 |
| o738    |       364 |        4 |
| o739    |       353 |        3 |
| o740    |       364 |        6 |
| o741    |       882 |        2 |
| o742    |       224 |        5 |
| o743    |       224 |        2 |
+---------+-----------+----------+






orders table
    +-----------------+------------+------------+
    |         orderid | ocardtype  |   odate    |
    +-----------------+------------+------------+
    |     o737        | Paypal     |            | 'OK
    |     o738        | MasterCard | 01.02.2012 | 'OK
    |     o739        | MasterCard | 02.02.2012 | 'OK
    |     o740        | Visa       | 03.02.2012 | 'OK
    |     o741        | Sofort     |            | 'OK
    |     o742        |            |            | 'ignore because ocardtype is empty
    |     o743        | MasterCard |            | 'ignore because Mastercard no odate
    +-----------------+------------+------------+
```

expected result

```
+-----------+------------------------+--------------+
| catalogid | ProcessedSucssessfully | NotProcessed |
+-----------+------------------------+--------------+
|       353 |o737,o739               |              |
|       364 |o738,o740               |              |
|       882 |o741                    |              |
|       224 |                        |o742,o743     |
+-----------+------------------------+--------------+
```

i have the following conditions which you can find in the case statment of above code

1. if `ocardtype` is empty then add `orderid` to `NotProcessed`
2. if `ocardtype` for some order is MasterCard or Visa and the odate is empty then add orderid to `NotProcessed`
3. if `ocardtype` is Paypal or Sofort, then don't check for odate and add the `orderid` to `ProcessedSucssessfully`

Comment: The first clue would be that number of open brackets is not same as the number of closed brackets. Ideally they should match.

Comment: You have 10 left parentheses and 12 right parentheses.  In other words, you have multiple basic syntax errors.  Correct those first, then see if you still have problems.  Also, when asking a question, you need to specify which type of SQL you are using, because they are all different.

Comment: Specify wich is your RDBMS, seems MS SQL Server, wich version?

Comment: @user1570048 there appears to be several things wrong with your syntax.  What exactly are you trying to do here?  Can you post some sample data and then the expected result?

Comment: @bluefeet sure i'll do it in a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this request

```
SELECT CatalogId, ProcessedSucssessfully = 
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + b.OrderId
              FROM oitmes b JOIN orders o ON b.OrderId = o.OrderId
              WHERE b.CatalogId = a.CatalogId
              AND (o.OcardtType in ('PayPal','Sofort') OR o.OcardtType in  ('mastercard','visa') and o.odate is not null)    
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),
                  NotProcessed =
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + c.OrderId
               FROM oitmes c JOIN orders o ON c.OrderId = o.OrderId
               WHERE c.CatalogId = a.CatalogId
               AND (o.OcardtType in ('mastercard') OR o.OcardtType is null) and o.odate is null
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM oitmes a
GROUP BY a.CatalogId
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/668b4/3)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the `FROM` clause before `CASE` and not after:

```
SELECT   ProductNumber, Category =
      CASE ProductLine
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'
         WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'
         WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'
         ELSE 'Not for sale'
      END,
   Name
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber
```

Other thing I can think of is that you are not returning true or false with `CASE` and that might getting you an error.